# If table column is NULL I want to set Long variable NULL instead of 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet which uses SQLite.

One table allows NULL values on a column. If I do the following and `COLUMN_ARTICLE_QUANTITY_GOODS_NON_PACKET` is NULL, `c.getLong` returns 0 and I want to get NULL instead of 0.

```
int goodsNonPckIdx =
            c.getColumnIndex(SqlConstants.COLUMN_ARTICLE_QUANTITY_GOODS_NON_PACKET);
articleQty.setGoodsNonPacket(c.getLong(goodsNonPckIdx));
```

By the way `GoodsNonPacket` is a `Long` (an object).

**How can I get null values from database?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c.getLong(goodsNonPckIdx)` will always return a `long` (primitive data type) value which can't be `null`.

You can probably use the [isNull](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull%28int%29) method to check if it is null or not and set the value based on that.